# Find center of physical screen (NOT viewport) with Javascript

Tags: javascript, window

is there a current and reliable way to find the center of the user's *physical* screen – not just the center of the viewport? Or are OS and browser behaviours too disparate to get any consistent information?

Right now I'm using `window.outerHeight / 2 + window.screenY - window.screen.height / 2` (and a similar logic for the horizontal position), which should give the offset between the viewport's center and the screen's, but it's not perfect:

- In fullscreen Chrome, Firefox, Vivaldi and Edge all give 0 (ie. the
  expected result)
- In a maximised window however, Chrome and Firefox give -20, while Vivaldi (despite being based on Chromium) gives 12 and Edge, -12. (I'm on W10.)

Does anyone have a good solution for this or at least a lead? :)

Comment: unless the browser is not in a full screen mode there is no way to do that, but if somehow you are able to check if the browser is in the full screen mode you can use `document.documentElement.getBoundingClientRect()` to get a `DOMRect` object - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: That's a shame. Thanks.